# How to set text to a control from resource file in design time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, windows-forms-designer

I want to know if there exists a way to set a control's `Text` property from a resource file in design time:

[image: Set Property]

Or this process can only be performed programatically?

Comment: Do you want to set the text property using a `.Resx` file that you made yourself or your actual requirement is localization?

Comment: The first one, @RezaAghaei.

Comment: I know to do that programmatically, but I don't how to set the control's `Text` property in design time.

Comment: The designer only serializes string for that property. You can not set the `Text` property to a resource value directly using designer, but you can somehow use an extender to set the resource key for your control at design-time and then use it at run-time. But in general I think using standard Localization mechanisms of windows forms is a better option.

Answer (score 6):

The designer only serializes string for `Text` property. You can not set the Text property to a resource value directly using designer.

Even if you open the `Form1.Designer.cs` file and add a line to initialization to set the `Text` property to a resource value like `Resource1.Key1`, after first change in designer, the designer replace your code by setting the string value of that resource for `Text` property.

In general I recommend using standard [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) mechanisms of windows forms, using `Localizable` and `Language` property of `Form`.

But if in some reason you want to use your resource file and want to use a designer-based solution, as good option you can create an [extender component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/d6c1xa43(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=5003235) to set the resource key for your control at design-time and then use it at run-time.

*Code for the extender component is at the end of the post.*

**Usage**

Make sure you have a resource file. For example `Resources.resx` in the properties folder. Also make sure you have some resource key/value in the resource file. For example Key1 with value = "Value1", Key2 with value = "Value2". Then:

1. Put a `ControlTextExtender` component on your form.
2. Using property grid set the `ResourceClassName` property of it to the full name of your resource file for example WindowsApplication1.Properties.Resources`
   [image]
3. Select each control you want to set its `Text` and using property grid set the value of `ResourceKey on controlTextExtender1` property to the resource key that you want.
   [image]

Then run the application and see the result.

**Result**

and here is an screenshot of result, and as you see, I even localized `Text` property of the form this way.

[image]

[image]

**Switch between Cultures at Run-Time**

You can switch between cultures at run-time, without need to close and reopen the form simply using:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa");
this.controlTextExtender1.EndInit();
```

**Implementation**

Here is a basic implementation of the idea:

```
[ProvideProperty("ResourceKey", typeof(Control))]
public class ControlTextExtender 
    : Component, System.ComponentModel.IExtenderProvider, ISupportInitialize
{
    private Hashtable Controls;
    public ControlTextExtender() : base() { Controls = new Hashtable(); }

    [Description("Full name of resource class, like YourAppNamespace.Resource1")]
    public string ResourceClassName { get; set; }

    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        if (extendee is Control)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public string GetResourceKey(Control control)
    {
        return Controls[control] as string;
    }

    public void SetResourceKey(Control control, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            Controls.Remove(control);
        else
            Controls[control] = key;
    }

    public void BeginInit() { }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        if (DesignMode)
            return;

        var resourceManage = new ResourceManager(this.ResourceClassName, 
                                                 this.GetType().Assembly);
        foreach (Control control in Controls.Keys)
        {
            string value = resourceManage.GetString(Controls[control] as string);
            control.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for controls, but not toolstrip items, datagridview columns and controls embedded in other controls, how do i fix this?

Comment: @Smith If you take a look at the logic of code, you will see that we just provide `ResourceKey` property for `Control` objects. That's because we are going to set `Text` property for them. But if we decide to also extend `Component` classes like `ToolTip`, which have different base class than `Control`, we can not rely on existence of `Text` property. For `DataGridViewColumn` types, as far as I know, you can not create an extender component which work also in column collection editor.