# Localization windows forms, exclude control parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, windows-forms-designer

I want to localize my windows forms project. I use resx files. The problem is resx files includes all the parameters of controls (label, textbox...) These parameters are buttonName for example like above

```
.>>buttonVazgec.Name     buttonMybutton
```

or

```
.>>textBoxYetkili.ZOrder   25
```

I do not want to localize these parameters. the worst thing about this behavior is when I try to change the form (adding a new textbox) I need to redesign for all languages.
how can I exclude these properties from my resource. can these properties be saved in a different partial resx or sth?

thanks

Comment: Several options: 1) process resource files (I was converting form.resx files into txt-files in past, which are then sent to translate and then imported back into resources) 2) write custom localizaton manager (e.g. using reflection to collect list of localize-able properties)  3) use 3d party translators (they don't have problems you describe).

Comment: can you suggest any third party translator if you have experienced?

Comment: You may find this post helpful:[How to set text to a control from resource file in design time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948734/how-to-set-text-to-a-control-from-resource-file-in-design-time) the answer shares idea and code of an extender component which allows you to localize text of controls using separate resource files.