# Changing CurrentUICulture at runtime in a Localizable Form in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, currentculture

I have been searching about how to change the language of a Form that has the `Localizable` attribute set to true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx

This is to set the language of the form, but this needs to be set before we instantiate the form. This cannot be called after this event.

Searching for information, I have seen the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738932/3286975 but, as a comment said, I have controls inside of a TabControl and a MenuStrip, so they aren't affected.

I have tried to modify this, by getting all the controls of the Form without luck.

[image]

[image]

In this menu I call the following callback:

```
    private void englishToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lang = (string) ((ToolStripMenuItem) sender).Tag;
        base.Culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
    }

    private void spanishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string lang = (string) ((ToolStripMenuItem) sender).Tag;
        base.Culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
    }
```

I change the Culture by using the Tag.

When I click it nothing happens. Also, I have modified a little bit the ApplyResources method from the mentioned answer.

```
private void ApplyResources(Control parent, CultureInfo culture)
{
        this.resManager.ApplyResources(parent, parent.Name, culture);

        foreach (Control ctl in parent.IterateAllChildren())
        {
            //this.ApplyResources(ctl, culture);
            this.resManager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name, culture);
        }
}
```

Where IterateAllChildren is the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725020/3286975

Also, I tried with (System.LINQ): `Controls.OfType<Label>()` (because I have one Label to test this) without luck...

[image]

[image]

But when I select the Spanish language, no text is changed.

So maybe, I'm failling with the childrens. Or maybe by calling the method `CreateCulture`, I don't know.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I have tested to get the Resource Manager of my form by the Culture Info and it returns the default one everytime:

```
 ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceManager(typeof(frmCredentials)).GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo(lang), true, true);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
            {
                string resourceKey = entry.Key.ToString();
                object resource = entry.Value; //resourceSet.GetString(resourceKey);
                if (resource.GetType().Equals(typeof(string)))
                    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}\nValue: {1}\n\n", resourceKey, (string) resource);
            }
```

Where `new CultureInfo(lang)`, I haved tested also: `new CultureInfo("es")` & `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` (CurrentUICulture) without luck. Is like it never exists or is replaced, but in my design and file explorer I can see the files.

**EDIT2:**

Maybe is because I'm using ILMerge to merge all dlls in a unique one. I'm reviewing this: [Single-assembly multi-language Windows Forms deployment (ILMerge and satellite assemblies / localization) - possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-windows-forms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-a)

**Reply to EDIT2:**

Yep, deleting ILMerge the problem is solved, and the first solution I gave resolves this. But for some reason, Spanish language is taken as the default language, and when I tried to get the resourceset from it, it didn't return me nothing.

Aso, I have set the Localizable attribute to false, and it didn't created a default resx file with values. I don't know if this is a good practice.

I will try something new...

Comment: I admit that the following isn't a great approach, but since you know you have a `TabControl` and a `MenuStrip`, you could modify your `IterateAllChildren` method to specifically watch for those controls and do special handling to ensure you cover all of their child controls.  Reinitializing the form (as @Isma suggested) would be a better approach if you can deal with the clearing of all the data in the form (e.g. by saving it first).

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067507/change-language-at-runtime-in-c-sharp-winform/21068497#21068497 The solution pointed out on that StackOverflow question works like a charm.

Comment: Well... This is a good aproach if you do for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411694/get-all-inherited-classes-of-an-abstract-class I appreciate your help, but I prefer something easier, if theren't more option, I will try this.

Comment: Instead of using ILMerge you can use [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/), this solves the namespace problems ILMerge frequently causes. [There is even a library that will automatically embed the files and add the assembly load code for you](https://github.com/Fody/Costura). (Actually the creator of IL merge responds in the comments of the first link *"As the author of ILMerge, I think this is fantastic! If I had known about this, I never would have written ILMerge."*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I have realized that several things are failing.

I have to say also that all the given help in this question is greatly appreciated, and also that the [LocalizedForm snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738932/3286975) is very useful.

The first issue is that I have realized is that the controls that are under a level of more than 1 in the child hierarchy with this solution doesn't work.

And iterating over all the controls is a expensive task. Maybe mine is worst but has less iterations (because I only seach for Controls with Text)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Current culture of this form
    /// </summary>
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Description("Current culture of this form")]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get { return this.culture; }
        set
        {
            if (this.culture != value)
            {
                ResourceSet resourceSet = new ComponentResourceManager(GetType()).GetResourceSet(value, true, true);
                IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> entries = resourceSet
                    .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                    .Where(x => x.Key.ToString().Contains(".Text"))
                    .Select(x => { x.Key = x.Key.ToString().Replace(">", "").Split('.')[0]; return x; });

                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in entries)
                {
                    if (!entry.Value.GetType().Equals(typeof(string))) return;

                    string Key = entry.Key.ToString(),
                           Value = (string) entry.Value;

                    try
                    {
                        Control c = Controls.Find(Key, true).SingleOrDefault();
                        c.Text = Value;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Control {0} is null in form {1}!", Key, GetType().Name);
                    }
                }

                this.culture = value;
                this.OnCultureChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I do is the following, first, I search for the **ResourceManager**, take care! Because here is the second issue and is that if you use `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture` instead `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` in some cases a new culture will be created and default values will be returned (`Form1.resx` values instead of `Form1.es.resx` values (for example)).

Once we have loaded all the value from the **resx file**, we iterate over all of them, and we delete the double >> (it appears in some cases) and we get the name of those **Controls** that only have declared the **Text attribute**.

The next step is find the **Control** and replace its Text...

Well, I have a little mess with the **derived classes**, that's why I created a **try-catch system**, because, **Controls.Find search in all the Derived Classes** I would prefer to be a little bit more specific but I don't know how... (That's why I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017882/injecting-a-menustripitem-to-a-derived-class-from-the-base-constructor))

With this we haven't to save any object because we won't clear and recreate them.

The main problem here wasn't the way I was doing this, because it was correct.
The problem is that **Assemblies merged do weird things** when you call for example this:

`ResourceSet resourceSet = new ComponentResourceManager(GetType()).GetResourceSet(value, true, true);`

The `value` will be the default... Something like that this **Culture doesn't exist**, and is because, the **merged Assembly** can't find the resx file.

So, I will try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` that @ScottChamberlain has suggested to me. Or **ILRepack** maybe.

Any help for optimization or ideas (in comments) of why this doesn't work will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

MVVM (Model - View - ViewModel) approach have some benefits which can be useful in your case.

Create new resource files for languages which you will use for localization. Working with form's own resource files can be little bid tricky because it regenerated every time you make change in the designer - so I think own resource file will be easier to maintain and even share with other forms and even projects.

```
LocalizationValues.resx // (default english), set Access Modifier to "Internal" or "Public"
    "Title": "Title"
    "Description": "Description"

LocalizationValues.es.resx
    "Title": "Título"
    "Description": "Descripción"
```

Visual Studio generate static class `LocalizationValues` with properties as keys of .resx file. So "Title" can be accessed as `LocalizationValues.Title`

Create "viewmodel" class which represents all texts you are using in localization. Class should implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
public class LocalizationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return LocalizationValues.Title;
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return LocalizationValues.Description;
        }
    }

    public void SetLanguage(string language)
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        // This is important, 
        // By raising PropertyChanged you notify Form to update bounded controls
        NotifyAllPropertyChanged();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyAllPropertyChanged()
    {
        // Passing empty string as propertyName
        // will indicate that all properties of viewmodel have changed
        NotifyPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in Form bind viewmodel to controls

```
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    private LocalizationViewModel _viewmodel;

    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewmodel = new LocalizationViewModel();

        // Bound controls to correspondent viewmodel's properties
        LblTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewmodel, "Title", true);
        LblDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", _viewmodel, "Description", true);
    }

    // Menu buttons to change language
    private void SpanishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _viewmodel.SetLanguage("es");
    }

    private void EnglishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _viewmodel.SetLanguage("en");
    }
}
```

Approach above will provide more benefits then only updating controls. You get clearly separated parts of your application, which can be tested independently from each other.

Comment: Your two calls to `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(...))` could be simplified. If you just did `NotifyPropertyChanged("")` raising a empty string or null to the `PropertyChanged` event signals that all properties have changed and all must be re-evaluated. The note for that is in [the remarks section of the documentation for the event itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - nice, wasn't aware about that. Documentation should be read carefully - will actually save  time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions to solve the problem, including the MVVM that mentioned in other answers. But you can consider some other options as well.

**Call ApplyResource on all controls**

You can set the currunt UI culture of the current thread and the call `ApplyResource` on all controls. To do so you need to create a method to return all controls, then just call `ApplyResource` on all controls, for examle:

```
private void englishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCulture("en-US");
}
private void persianToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCulture("fa-IR");
}
public void SetCulture(string cultureName)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureName);
    var resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(this.GetType());
    GetChildren(this).ToList().ForEach(c => {
        resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name);
    });
}
public IEnumerable<Control> GetChildren(Control control)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetChildren(ctrl)).Concat(controls);
}
```

**Creating a Text Localization Extender Component**

You also can create an extender component that can be used at design-time as well as run-time and assign some resource file and resource keys to controls. This way you can simply switch between languages by changing the current UI culture of the current thread. Just to see an example of the idea, take a look at this post:

- [How to set text to a control from resource file in design time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33948734/3110834)

Comment: My main problem now is that assemblies that use ILMerge doesn't work. So, I have to figure it out, thanks for your answer!

Comment: It can be your next question. Don't mix multiple questions in a single post :)

Comment: I will need to do this, and I will post my solution, but thanks!

Comment: I can say that provided solutions will solve your problem in a common application. I don't have any idea about the problem in a different case. I'll take a look at your other question if you post some [mcve] :)

Comment: By the way, don't miss the second idea. It's highly extensible. In most cases I prefer my first solution, but in some cases I've extended the second idea and used it to provide localization to text of controls using design-time support.