# Injecting a MenuStripItem to a derived class from the base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, load, menustrip

I want to inject a **MenuStrip Item** or create a new one if it doesn't exists (but this is a different question) from the **base constructor**, the logic is the following:

```
public class LocalizedForm : Form 
{
    public LocalizedForm() 
    {
        Shown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            MenuStrip menu = null;
            if (HasValidMenu(out menu))
                LanguageManager.AttachMenu(menu); //Language Manager will inject MenuStripItems to the passed MenuStrip
        };
    }

    protected bool HasValidMenu(out MenuStrip menu)
    {
        try
        {
            menu = Controls.OfType<MenuStrip>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Dock == DockStyle.Top);
            return menu != null;
        }
        catch
        {
            menu = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and two childs:

```
public partial class frmMain : LocalizedForm 
{

}

public partial class frmCredentials : LocalizedForm 
{

}
```

Why I use **Shown event**? That's because the **MenuStrip** will not be found in the **Controls** until it is rendered or loaded.

Well, my main problem now is that the menu options are created twice instead one time.

As you can see there:

[image: menu options duplicated]

By this reason I have changed the following things:

`protected bool HasValidMenu(out MenuStrip menu)` to `protected bool HasValidMenu(string name, out MenuStrip menu)`

The call has been changed to:

`if (HasValidMenu(out menu))` to `if (HasValidMenu(GetType().Name, out menu))`

This will return the main type name from where this was called.

And the magic:

`menu = Controls.OfType<MenuStrip>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Dock == DockStyle.Top);` to

`menu = Application.OpenForms[name].Controls.OfType<MenuStrip>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Dock == DockStyle.Top);`

But for some reason, Shown event doesn't affect to derived classes. I have testing by calling the Load or Shown event of derived classes by using `Application.OpenForms[name]` but this is also null.

So, what can I do?