# Why localization doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization

I try to write simple C# project to test how localication work.
I did how here is written.

[How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

I think I use the same like in the questions/1142802.
But it doesn't work in my Demo project.
I can't explain why.
This is why I attached Demo project.

I have two resource files for FRA and RUS languages.

And try to switch language using next code

```
private void rbFra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-Fr");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

  textBox1.Text = Properties.Resources.String1;
}

private void rgEng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

  textBox1.Text = Properties.Resources.String1;
}

private void rbRus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

  textBox1.Text = Properties.Resources.String1;
}
```

But the result is always in English.

I think that Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ... should force to reload resource file and String1 return text from loaded resource.

Here is the DemoProject https://yadi.sk/d/4zEWVhso3Q4eqV

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would add the Strings inside a single resource and index them that way Resource.String1...String3 try that..

Comment: It's not completely clear why. If there is a standard mechanism for working with the localization of resources, then why not use it. 2. One file is not convenient for developers who want to add a new language.

Comment: then you need to figure out how to access 1 of 3 different resource files.. do a simple google search then

Comment: Does not the code <
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-Fr"); >
do it automatically?

Comment: how would it know what Resource file you are trying to reference...? ask yourself that..

Comment: At compile time VS create "fr" and "ru" folder in "bin\Debug".
So when the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is changed it uses these folders to load TestLocalization.resources.dll with the necessary resources.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should restart your test application and assign the desired culture on program startup BEFORE opening the first form, e.g. in the `Main()` method. From my knowledge there is no easy way in WinForms to dynamically switch the culture during runtime.

Comment: @KBO No need to restart. Reopening the form is just for cases which the user is using Windows Forms Localization using `Localizable` and `Language` property. Also even in that case, the problem can be solved without reopening the form.

Comment: @Reza Thanks for the comment, but in non-trivial apps you normally have a bunch of thread pool and worker threads. If you want to change the language of the entire app, the easiest way is to restart from scratch and set the `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` additionally. So all threads, created in the app, have the right language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your settings:

- You are putting your language resource files in a different folder than the neutral resource file. So the namespace would be different. Currently your neutral resource file is in `Properties` folder and the other resources are in root folder of the project.
- The first part of the the file names of the language resources should be the same as the neutral resource file. So since the neutral resource file name is `Resources.resx`, those language files should be `Resources.ru.resx` and `Resources.fr.resx`. They lack `s` character at the end of file name.

After fixing those problems it will work well.

Apart from what you are trying to do, you can take a look at Windows Forms Localization feature:

- [How to make multi language app in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32989100/3110834)
- [Changing UI Culture at run-time in a Windfows Forms Localizable Application.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46017814/3110834)

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.
I did not know that the filename is part of the namespace for resources.